# php str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

How to str_replace

```
</div> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

to

```
</div> 
</li> 
</ul>
aaa
```

All the tags in a new line.

I tried

```
$str = str_replace('</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>', '</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>\n\raaa', $str);
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
$str =<<<EOT
</div>
</li>
</ul>
EOT;

$str = str_replace("</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>", "</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>\n\raaa", $str);  

echo $str;
```

Comment: This is a poorly described question.  If your actual input has more markup in it, you should represent that in your question.  Manipulating html is more accurately done with a dom parser like DomDocument or similar so that you don't accidentally "over-match" / "over-replace".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` in single quotes is a literal `\` and a literal `n`, rather than a `\n`, to get the line breaks you need to use double quotes:

```
$str = str_replace("</div>\r\n</li>\r\n</ul>", "</div>\r\n</li>\r\n</ul>\r\naaa", $str);
```

Also, you should be replacing `\r\n` not `\n\r` as Windows line breaks are a carriage return `\r` followed by a line break `\n`.

Comment: @Mark Elliot, @PeeHaa. not working, see my `UPDATE CODE` code.

Answer (score 2):

When you use single quotes the `\r\n` will be treated as string.

Use double quotes instead:

```
$str = str_replace("</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>", "</div>\n\r</li>\n\r</ul>\n\raaa", $str);
```

**EDIT**

Can't you just do:

```
$str = str_replace('</ul>', "</ul>\n\raaa", $str);
```

If that isn't suited it's better to resort to rexeg.

Comment: no, because there still have other `<ul>` tag, and I do not want to replace all of them. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't you just want this?

```
$str = $str . "\n\raaa";
```

Second, (see Mark Elliot's answer about single versus double quotes)

Comment: Not if there's markup/string content that follows the `</ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not string concat?

```
$str .= "\r\naaa";
```